# UISplitView with preferredDisplayMode primaryOverlay covers entire screen and overlaps UITabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to use UISplitView in UITabBar. I want master(left side view) splitview to act as a Slide Menu for which I have set splitview property preferredDisplayMode 'primaryOverlay' which can overlay detail screen and goes back on selecting item from menu.

But here the master view covers the entire screen including UITabbar. Can we have any solution that can just overlay the screen above UITabBar so that TabBar remains accessible?

Attaching the screenshot for clear idea..

[image]

Comment: Reduce the `UISplitView`'s height to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

`UISplitViewController` by default presents primary view as overlay when in portrait mode. You will have to subclass `UISplitViewController` and then force it to show all the time like,

`splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible`

As far as I know, Apple recommends you to use Split view controller as the root view controller of your application.

But if you want to use tab bar controller as root and if you don't want the split view to be overlapping over the tab bar then, you need to make use of container view controller by using `UIContainerView` and then embed your split view controller inside the container view.This will solve what you are expecting,I guess